# How to get the list of running GUI applications in the Unity Launcher?

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash, process, launcher

I need a list with only those apps that are currently open/running in Dash, the ones that have that small white arrow(s) on the left side of the icon.

Is there any way to get it?

[image: dash with arrows screenshoot]

Comment: What is the context and how would you need the list to be available (in what form)?

Comment: List of open windows ? Can be easily done, but as Jacob said, we'd probably need to know more info

Comment: Related, and very likely a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/483554/295286

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do it with `qdbus` and `org.ayatana.bamf` interface.

List of open applications by `.desktop` file:

```
$ qdbus org.ayatana.bamf /org/ayatana/bamf/matcher \                           
> org.ayatana.bamf.matcher.RunningApplicationsDesktopFiles
/usr/share/applications/compiz.desktop
/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
/usr/share/applications/x-terminal-emulator.desktop
```

Using `org.ayatana.bamf.matcher.RunningApplications` and  `org.ayatana.bamf.view.Name` methods

```
$ qdbus org.ayatana.bamf /org/ayatana/bamf/matcher  \                          
> org.ayatana.bamf.matcher.RunningApplications | \                             
> xargs -I {} qdbus org.ayatana.bamf {} org.ayatana.bamf.view.Name
Firefox Web Browser
MY CUSTOM TERMINAL
Compiz
```

Comment: Now that is impressive!

Comment: @JacobVlijm There's more variations on this, but they have specific purpose and require more code and parsing.  I just pasted the simplest ones here. But thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Interesting question.

As always, there are different ways to get a list of these applications, each of them with specific ad- and disadvantages.

### Getting a list of processes, represented in the Launcher, using the window list

Since only applications with a (mapped) window appear in the Launcher, using:

```
wmctrl -lp
```

(`wmctrl` is not installed by default), we can get a list of opened windows and the process- id the windows belong to. The format of the output is:

```
0x05204641  0 12618  jacob-System-Product-Name verhaal (~) - gedit
```

where for us most important information is in:

- the first string (`0x05204641`); this is the *window -id*
- the third string (`12618`); this is the *process id* (pid) the window belongs to, and,
- the last section (`verhaal (~) - gedit`); this is the window *name*.

Once we have the pid, we can look up the corresponding process *name* by the command:

```
ps -p <pid> -o comm=
```

We can script the steps above, and list the output(s) for existing windows, looking like (using `python`):

```
{'gnome-terminal', 'nautilus', 'gedit', 'GuitarPro.exe', 'firefox', 'thunderbird', 'soffice.bin'}
```

#### Complications

This seems straightforward. However, as always, reality is a bit more complicated. There are a few exceptions and complications we need to take care of:

1. Some windows will belong to [pid 0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83322/which-process-has-pid-0), which will raise an error when trying to get their properties. Windows of `Idle` (`python` IDE) or `tkinter` are such windows.
2. Some windows are no "real" or windows, like transient windows (windows, which are called from, and belonging to other windows) or for example the desktop itself. These windows are listed as windows in the output of `wmctrl`, but do not appear separately in Dash.
3. In some cases, the application's name is quite different from the process name, for example in the case of `LibreOffice` where all modules have the process name of `soffice.bin`. At the same time, running the *command* `soffice.bin` will not work. In case you need to identify the *modules* (`Calc`, `Writer` etc.) separately, you'd need to get additional information, from the window's *name* for example.
4. Another example is the process name of `gnome-terminal`, as it appears in the process list, as in the output of `ps -e ww`. In 14.04, `gnome-terminal` appears as `gnome-terminal`, however, in 15.04 / 15.10 it shows: `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server`.

#### What we need to fix *at least*

To fix the most important issues above, you need to:

- add a check if the window is a "real" or "normal" window, checking with

  ```
  xprop -id <window_id>
  ```

  If the output includes the line:

  ```
  _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
  ```

  The window is a valid window in the sense of the Unity Launcher
- To fix the process name of `gnome-terminal` in `15.x` (assuming you want the presented process name to be `gnome-terminal`) we need to add an exception, to rename the process name into `gnome-terminal` if it appears as 
  `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server`

#### Script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    listed = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    listed = []

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

def check_wtype(w_id):
    # check the type of window; only list "NORMAL" windows
    return "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in get(["xprop", "-id", w_id])

def get_process(w_id):
    # get the name of the process, owning the window
    proc = get(["ps", "-p", w_id, "-o", "comm="])
    proc = "gnome-terminal" if "gnome-terminal" in proc else proc
    return proc

wlist = [l.split() for l in subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"])\
         .decode("utf-8").splitlines()]

validprocs = set([get_process(w[2]) for w in wlist if check_wtype(w[0]) == True])

if listed == "-list":
    for p in validprocs:
        print(p)
else:
    print(validprocs)
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs `wmctrl`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `get_running.py`
3. run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/get_running.py
   ```

   It will output like:

   ```
   {'gnome-terminal', 'nautilus', 'gedit', 'GuitarPro.exe', 'firefox', 'thunderbird', 'soffice.bin'}
   ```

   or, run with the argument `-list`:

   ```
   thunderbird
   nautilus
   gnome-terminal
   firefox
   gedit
   GuitarPro.exe
   soffice.bin
   ```

#### Notes

From your question, it is not completely clear what is exactly the purpose of the found list. If you need to have the application's name, as it appears in the interface ("readable" names), a completely different approach might be suited:

- All globally installed applications do have a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`. In far most cases, we can conclude the process name *and* the interface name of the application from its `.desktop` file. Using this information, we could relatively easy create a list of running GUI applications, presented by their "readable" name.

Also in this case however, reality is also more complicated then theory, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229254/how-do-i-determine-an-applications-process-name).