# How can I find out what app is running (actual name, not published name)?

Tags: unity

I've just been through the massive long process this morning of trying to identify a running application. It was for the purpose of reporting a bug this morning, but I ended up posting a question about it to AskUbuntu instead.

I fluked finding the answer this time.

I tried starting `gnome-system-monitor` (published name: "System Monitor"), but I couldn't work out which was the application I was looking for.

I tried going to the application's menu > About but is doesn't show the actual name of the application there. Here's a screenshot of `gnome-software` > About, which only shows the published name of "Ubuntu Software".
[image: Ubuntu Software > About]

I did a web search for "ubuntu software" to see if any search results showed the name of the application. I found [a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center) that says "Development was ended in 2015 and in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it was replaced with GNOME Software instead". I followed the link to [GNOME Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software) but the name of the application is not shown there either.

Therefore I wasn't able to report the bug, so I came to AskUbuntu. I did a search for "ubuntu software" and saw the name "gnome-software" somewhere.

I opened a terminal, used the command `gnome-software`, and the correct application started.

I ended up asking a question in AskUbuntu instead of reporting the bug. However, I have had this same problem many times over the last 10 years or so, and I would dearly like to solve it once and for all.

Is there a quick and easy way to identify the **actual** name of a currently running application?

PS This question was marked as a duplicate "This question already has an answer here:
[How do I determine an application's process name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229254/how-do-i-determine-an-applications-process-name) 1 answer", which effectively answers "No" to my question "Is there a quick and easy way to identify the **actual** name of a currently running application?", but in actual fact the answer I received from @waltinator seems to provide a method (via `xprop` command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xwininfo` (see `man xwininfo`), from the `x11-utils` package. To demonstrate, I ran `xwininfo -all` in a terminal window, and following the prompt, clicked on this window. The first part of what it said is:

```
$ xwininfo -all

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0x4600007 "unity - How can I find out what app is running (actual name, not published name)? - Ask Ubuntu"

  Root window id: 0x7d (the root window) "QupZilla"
  Parent window id: 0x2403a37 (has no name)
     1 child:
     0x4600008 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +65+51

  Absolute upper-left X:  66
  Absolute upper-left Y:  52
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 1696
  Height: 1148
  Depth: 24
...
```

There are also `xlsclients` and `xprop` (see the `man page`) that may be of use.

Comment: Ah ha!

`xwininfo` doesn't name the process.
`xlsclients` is more useful, giving a list of possible candidates.
`xprop` seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no default way to do this.

On the command line you can use `xprop` to get information about a window (the cursor will change and you are expected to click on the window).

The output usually has a line starting with `_NET_WM_PID` that contains the PID of the program, and you can use e.g.

```
ps -o comm -p THE_PID
```

to find the program's command.

You can put this all together in a shell script and use `zenity` for a graphical display:

```
#!/bin/sh
zenity --info --text "$(ps --no-headers -o comm -p $(xprop | awk '/^_NET_WM_PID/ {print $3}'))"
```

Save this somewhere as a file, make it executable and assign a hotkey to it.

I guess there are some cases where it doesn't work or displays a wrong result but usually it should be at least helpful.

Comment: yuk

That's at least a 4-step process

Comment: I see now that the second sentence of your answer seems to be the answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grep -i "access prompt" /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gcr-prompter.desktop:Name=Access Prompt
```

In this example, the application's "common" name is `Access Prompt` and the name that shows up in the output of something like `ps -o pid,ppid,stime,time,command -u $USER` is `gcr-prompter`.

This approach has two limitations:
  - it only looks in `/usr/share/applications` (because that's where most .desktop files are found). But some .desktop files may only be in `~/.local/share/applications`.
  - depending on how you define a "application", some applications may not have a .desktop file. In such cases, the application's "common" name and actual name will be the same.

Comment: yuk

Not all-encompassing enough. ie. it will sometimes work, and sometimes not.